# Can't change subnet, but some IPs are now starting to resolve externally. How to force to resolve internally?

Tags: dns, windows-server-2003

My subnet was set onto 192.126.92.X many years ago by mistake, now we can't fix the subnet using the classic 192.168.1.X

But now some of the IPs are resolving externally.

When I did tracert 192.126.92.91 last year, for example, I read

client91 [192.126.92.91] (that's correct)

Today I read  cito.4cheapshoppingdeals.net [192.126.92.91]  (this is a problem)

We have windows 2003 server as DNS & primary domain controller.

In each client I have 192.126.92.1 as DNS

On the server I have the OpenDNS DNS.

How to fix it without changing subnet details ?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  How are your IPs assigned?  Have you changed some to 192.168.1.X or whatever?  Is something preventing a change of your internal network to the subnet you wish?

Comment: I haven't touched anything yet. We can't change internal network  subnet due to the too many services already running on these IP that we don't have direct control over (it's a local gov. facility) like video surveillance devices, network printers, etc. If we change subnet we probably can't print anymore, for example.

Answer (score 0):

You're using a routable IPv4 address space that has been allocated/assigned to another entity/organization.

The only way to fix it is to reconfigure your network to use one of the RFC1918 IPv4 address spaces or to use a routable address space that has been allocated/assigned to your organization.

Comment: what I would try is to avoid our DNS to resolve some addresses externally. is it possible in any way?

Comment: Why is your DNS resolving those ip addresses? Do you have devices querying for the PTR records for those ip addresses?

Comment: please take a look at this screenshot   http://i58.tinypic.com/15rziqf.jpg  

I need to run Look@LAN Network Monitor on a daily basis, in order to have notification that a device has been turned on/off. But now I can't read the netbios / host name anymore